# Exception:Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, bigint

My database column is of type *bigint* and has values that are phone numbers. It shows error on the button click event. The error is in the line:

```
_bal.phone = Convert.ToInt32(txtphone.Text);
```

Why is this happening?

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    _bal.name = txtname.Text;
    _bal.age = Convert.ToInt32(txtage.Text);
    _bal.email = txtemail.Text;
    _bal.password = txtpassword.Text;
    _bal.phone = Convert.ToInt32(txtphone.Text);




    if (btnsave.Text == "SAVE")
    {
        _bal.emp_insert();
    }
    else if (btnsave.Text == "UPDATE")
    {
        _bal.Lid = int.Parse(ViewState["Loginid"].ToString());
        _bal.emp_update();
    }

    fill_grd();
}

protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    _bal.Lid = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    if (e.CommandName == "editing")
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = _bal.emp_edit();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
            txtage.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["age"].ToString();
            txtemail.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
            txtpassword.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
            txtphone.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["phone"].ToString();
        }
        btnsave.Text = "UPDATE";
        ViewState["Loginid"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }

    else if (e.CommandName == "deleting")
    {
        _bal.emp_delete();
        fill_grd();
    }
}
```

Comment: >The int type represents signed 32-bit integers with values between  –2147483648 and 2147483647.

Comment: not able to solve error.plz help

Comment: If the entered phone number exceeded the maximum value , it should throw an exception .

Comment: I am just new to it could you plz help

Comment: use the nchar data type for phone number field in your database and then use it as a string.

Comment: what about this-_bal.phone = txtphone.Text; Do I need to convert ? And how?

Comment: I had used nchar(10) in my d/b

Comment: Then use `nchar(20)`

Comment: it should work just fine

Comment: after you do this , you don't need to use  **Convert.ToInt3();**

Comment: it works fine .

Comment: thanks but why it was not taking with nchar(10) as I entered only 10 digits.

Comment: Yes!  nchar(10) means that it can hold only 10 characters at most

Comment: You should only use numeric data types when the data you store is intended for numeric operations. Store it as a string otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Int32 can accept values between –2147483648 and 2147483647. The phone number you are inputting could be crossing this range and that's why you are getting this error.

**Suggestion**: As you mentioned that you are using nchar in your database, please use string data type to represent phone number field. OR if you are stick to use integer then use Int64 datatype. :)

Comment: `nchar` can hold "Text" data , he just needed to maximize its length.
Plus; There is no `string` nor `integer` data types in D.B.

Comment: Yeah! that's right. I was suggesting to use string or integer(long) in c# where conversion was applied "Convert.ToInt32(txtphone.Text);". Thanks

Comment: if he did that , an exception will be thrown in case he entered more than 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** For phone numbers you can use strings. If using **Microsoft SQL Server Database** you can set it as follow.

```
/* SQL Code */
[PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX)
```

Also, **C#** version will look as follow.

```
// C# class that will provide value to a Database
```

> ```
> public class PhoneNumber
> {
> public string Number { get; set; }
> }
> ```

If you would like to convert it into an integer value, the closest you will get to is by using **long** which has a max value of **9,223,372,036,854,775,808** and can be used as follow.

> ```
> string value = "9223372036854775808";
> long myValue = long.Parse(value);
> ```

The **long** data type can be use to convert Milliseconds Time Stamps to Standard or UTC date and time.

**For example:**

> ```
> string time = "1645532778236";
>
> long trying = long.Parse(time);
>
> DateTime now = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
> DateTime myDateTime= now.AddMilliseconds(trying);
> ```

[Most common](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhYhA.png)